# I'm having trouble understanding this specific notation in Ghidra

Tags: disassembly, x86, ghidra

I'm reversing a code construct I created to learn Ghidra, and it looks different to what it is in GDB. I was wondering if anyone could clarify what the highlighted LEA instruction means: [I don't know how it should be read]

[image: Screenshot of the disassembly in Ghidra]

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 3):

`LEA` means "Load Effective Address", i.e. instead of loading into the EAX register the *content* at the address ESP+8, it loads directly the *address*, i.e. the content of the register ESP increased by 8.

For illustration, if in the **ESP** register (Extended Stack Pointer) is the value **1000**, the situation may be as this:

[image]

Then your instruction `LEA EAX, [ESP+8]` loads into the **EAX** register the number **1008** — **the address of the 3<sup>rd</sup> value in the stack**.

In other words, the **EAX** will contain the **address** (a pointer) to the value 531.

*Compare:*

If you replace the `LEA` instruction with the `MOV` one:

```
LEA EAX, [ESP+8]    ; original (LEA): EAX = 1008
MOV EAX, [ESP+8]    ; replaced (MOV): EAX =  531
```

then the **EAX** register will be loaded with the *value in the stack*, i.e. **531**.

---

*Notes:*

1. **Why a pointer into stack?**
   Because arguments of functions are generally put into the stack.
   So in your code you probably obtained *a pointer to the particular (2<sup>nd</sup> ?) argument.*
2. **What the part `EAX => local_18` means?**

   Ghidra's decompiler (to C language) doesn't know the original instructions (and variable names), so it creates names as your `local_18`.

   In the listing (disassembly) `EAX => local_18` means something as:

   > “In this location, your variable `local_18` is used in the form of the  **EAX** register”.

   (This variable is not in the memory — its value is directly in the **EAX** register.)

Comment: Do you mean that the address of [ESP + local_18] is loaded into EAX, and ESP is increased by 8? [I'm rephrasing what you said for clarification]

Comment: No, ESP itself is not increased. For example, if in the ESP is the number 100, then after performing the highlighted instruction in the EAX registry will be 108 and in the ESP still 100. `local_18` has nothing with this instruction, it's only the Ghidra's hint (meaning that the result (108) will be saved in the variable `local_18`).

Comment: This is what I'm seeing: LEA EAX=>local_18, [ESP + 0x8] I don't understand where the [ESP + 0x8] comes from and I don't understand what the "EAX => local_18" shows

Comment: I  extended my answer with an illustration and the description.